# Почему -1L > 1UL?

Tags: c, типы

При изучении преобразования типов в Си столкнулся с неочевидной для меня вещью:

```
-1L > 1UL
```

Почему это именно так, разве эти два значения не должны быть равны друг-другу?

Comment: Потому что при переполнении, `-1L` == `MAX_UL`.

Comment: Вообще-то это, насколько я помню, UB... Но происходит следующее: -1 превращается в 0xFF..FF в беззнаковом варианте, что, понятно, больше 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, как "при изучении преобразования типов в Си" вы пришли к выводу, что "эти два значения должны быть равны друг-другу".

При смешении в бинарном операторе знакового и беззнакового типа одинаковой ширины, знаковое значение неявно приводится к беззнаковому типу. Т.е. вы имеете дело фактически с

```
(unsigned long) -1L > 1UL
```

При преобразовании к беззнаковому типу значение `-1` берется по модулю 2<sup>N</sup> (где `N` - ширина типа) и дает в результате 2<sup>N</sup>-1, то есть `ULONG_MAX`, который никак не равен `1UL`.

Answer (score 2):

Потому, что перед сравнением операнды неявно приводятся к единому типу, в данном случае `-1L` приводится к `unsigned long`.

Другой вопрос, почему именно `-1L` приводится к `unsigned long` а не `1UL` к `long`, ведь тогда результат был бы противоположным. И действительно, `-1L < 1U`, потому, что в данном случае `1U` приводится к типу `long` а не наоборот.

Существует четкий набор правил неявных преобразований (информация на английском есть [тут](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/INT02-C.+Understand+integer+conversion+rules)), но каким бы четким он не был, полностью интуитивным это его не делает, так что типы в этом случае желательно приводить явно.

```c
(unsigned long)-1L > 1UL
```

или

```c
-1L > (long)1UL
```